# BehaviorSubject (in Ionic Project) behaves strangely after update to latest Angular (v6 to v7)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, behaviorsubject

it's relly driving me nuts.

I've checked out a very simple [ionic v4 Project with a login flow](https://github.com/meumobi/meu-starter.login-flow.ionic-v4).

The demo worked perfectly fine, but since this project is already 5 months old, I've decided to create a new ionic project with the latest ionic cli and put the source into the new one... with the latest stable ionic dependencies.

But then the rxJS-BehaviorSubject (authState$) acts totally weird, see screen shot.

Code: https://github.com/meumobi/meu-starter.login-flow.ionic-v4/blob/master/src/app/core/auth/auth.service.ts

The Code (I've added some console.logs to the isAuthenticated() method):

```
console.log('isAuthenticated: ', this.authState$.getValue());
console.log('isAuthenticated: ', this.authState$);
```

The Console:

[image]

So what happened:

The getValue() returns the initial value, where as the printed object contains the correct value (true). This seems strange to me as they're both called right after each other.

When I change back the versions (to the original package.json) it will work again:

[image]

The update of the ionic project updated the angular version from v6.1 to v7.2 (including its deps) and TypeScript from 2.9 to 3.1.

RXJS has been updated from 6.2.2 to 6.3.3.

I would be really cool if you could tell me what's going on.

**Update:**

I might have tracked it down to one single dependency that causes this issue.

Last one working: "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.17"
Not working: anything higher than @ionic/angular@4.0.0-beta.17.

When creating a new ionic project, it ships with 4.1.0. Which means that it cannot work with a new project.

Thanks so much in advance,

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Try to access directly the value

```
this.authState$.value
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. If I change back the all dependencies to the old version, it works again (with both (.value and .getValue())).

Comment: Please push your code to a new branch in your repo and i will look into it

Comment: https://github.com/mastix/meu-starter.login-flow.ionic-v4 (Just run npm i and ionic serve). If you're logged in you should be able to access "home". If not, "Home" should not open. If you want to see it working, change the ionic angular version from 4.1.2 to "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.17".

Comment: BTW: I have tracked it down to one single dependency that causes this issue.

Last one working: "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-beta.17"
Not working: anything higher than @ionic/angular@4.0.0-beta.17.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it as observable to subscribe the data. Please use like this

```
 public _auth$:Observable<boolean> =this.authState$.asObservable();
 this._auth.subscribe(data=>{console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: I don't want to subscribe as I just want to use the standard behavior (not the observer pattern). So a getValue() should be possible. Eg. see this: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0